# ios 10 crash log Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Tags: ios

Can someone help me to solve this problem！
I can't find the solution, a long time, this random crash

**crash log**

> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
>
> Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000018
>
> Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11,
>
> Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb Terminating Process:
>   exc handler [0] Triggered by Thread:  0
>
> Filtered syslog: None found
>
> Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread Thread 0
>   Crashed: 0   libsystem_blocks.dylib           0x0000000188c5ea1c
>   _Block_release + 132
>
> 1   Foundation                        0x000000018a98b10c
>   -[NSBlockObservationSink dealloc] + 48
>
> 2   Foundation                        0x000000018a98b10c
>   -[NSBlockObservationSink dealloc] + 48
>
> 3   Foundation                        0x000000018a98acb4
>   -[_NSConcreteObservation dealloc] + 60
>
> 4   Foundation                        0x000000018a83a338 empty + 72
>
> 5   Foundation                        0x000000018a7873b0
>   -[NSConcreteMapTable removeAllItems] + 84
>
> 6   UIKit                             0x000000019051281c
>   -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _clearLayoutVariableObservationsOnlyToSupportTAMICChange:] + 68
>
> 7   UIKit                             0x000000018fcc0f3c
>   __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 408
>
> 8   Foundation                        0x000000018a7ac510 -[NSISEngine
>   withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 168
>
> 9   UIKit                             0x000000018fbbd7cc
>   -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:] + 224
>
> 10  UIKit                             0x000000018fcc1104
>   __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2 + 196
>
> 11  UIKit                             0x000000018fcc0fd8
>   __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 564
>
> 12  Foundation                        0x000000018a7ac510 -[NSISEngine
>   withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 168
>
> 13  UIKit                             0x000000018fbbd7cc
>   -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:] + 224
>
> 14  UIKit                             0x000000018fbbcf58
>   __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 120
>
> 15  Foundation                        0x000000018a7ac510 -[NSISEngine
>   withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 168
>
> 16  UIKit                             0x000000018fbbcdf0
>   -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 820
>
> 17  UIKit                             0x000000018feba268
>   __UIViewWasRemovedFromSuperview + 172
>
> 18  UIKit                             0x000000018fbbbe6c
>   -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 512
>
> 19  meiliyue                          0x00000001007f64a8 0x1000f8000 +
>   7333032
>
> 20  UIKit                             0x000000018fbfa214
>   -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 492
>
> 21  UIKit                             0x000000018fbf9d38
>   -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 312
>
> 22  UIKit                             0x000000018fbf9b78
>   -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 160
>
> 23  QuartzCore                        0x000000018d083404
>   CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 260
>
> 24  libdispatch.dylib                 0x0000000188c091c0
>   _dispatch_client_callout + 16
>
> 25  libdispatch.dylib                 0x0000000188c0dd6c
>   _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1000
>
> 26  CoreFoundation                    0x0000000189d2df2c
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** + 12
>
> 27  CoreFoundation                    0x0000000189d2bb18 __CFRunLoopRun +
>   1660
>
> 28  CoreFoundation                    0x0000000189c5a048
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
>
> 29  GraphicsServices                  0x000000018b6dd198 GSEventRunModal
>   + 180
>
> 30  UIKit                             0x000000018fc2c818 -[UIApplication
>   _run] + 684
>
> 31  UIKit                             0x000000018fc27550
>   UIApplicationMain + 208
>
> 32  meiliyue                          0x000000010010af78 0x1000f8000 +
>   77688
>
> 33  libdyld.dylib                     0x0000000188c3c5b8 start + 4

Comment: format it properly

Comment: thank you for advice,this is my first time to use stackoverflow,

Comment: @Q.QF: Have you got solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

plug your iphone to itunes and update ios to ios 10.2.1 cause ios 10.2.1 have new security patches that might be helpfull for solve your problem so try it

Comment: OK ,Thank you for advice